# Why is OSX skipping symbols during linking - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, clang

**UPDATE** when I switch from "g++" to "c++" everything compiles and links fine.  It's my understanding both of those map to clang, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

====

I've got a Makefile that works fine on Ubuntu Linux to compile a JNI implementation for a Java Native project.  It makes use of my own static library "libpt.a".

I'm trying to have the Makefile compile on Yosemite OSX.  It mostly does, but it's failing to link against just a handful of symbols in libpt.a (which I have specifically recompiled on OSX in this case).

```
g++  -L. -shared -o "libphoto_jni.dylib" PhotoNativeInterface.o -lpt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_parseWpiEnumString", referenced from:
      parseWpiAngle(char const*) in PhotoNativeInterface.o
      parseWpiCategory(char const*) in PhotoNativeInterface.o
      parseWpiColor(char const*) in PhotoNativeInterface.o
      parseWpiProcessingQuality(char const*) in PhotoNativeInterface.o
```

However, the symbol appears to be right there:

```
$ ls -al libpt.a
-rw-r--r--  1 jdowdell  110244447  2493728 Dec 14 13:23 libpt.a
$ nm libpt.a
[redacted]
libpt.a(lib.cc.o):
[redacted]
0000000000000000 T _parseWpiEnumString
[redacted]
$ ar -x libpt.a lib.cc.o
$ file lib.cc.o
lib.cc.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

If it matters:

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: That error *really* shouldn't happen when building a `.dylib` - it implies that `-shared` isn't doing the right thing. Can you try with `-Wl,-dylib` instead of `-shared`?

Comment: @Petesh, same result with -Wl,-dylib.  I don't know OSX well, but I think even though it doesn't have to have all symbols in the result, it still needs to know where they come from, in order to setup the .dylib dependency

Comment: There isn't a `libpt.dylib` there that may be causing problems? (my first comment was erroneous - OSX compiles with `-undefined error`)

Comment: No libpt.dylib.  Also see update above

Comment: when you use `g++` it defaults to using `libstdc++`, when you use `c++` it defaults to using `libc++`, this would explain some linking errors, but for an `extern "C"` function I'm surprised that it would affect it in that manner. (hmmm… looks like newer clang doesn't have this behaviour any more - g++ links with libc++ now as well)